# Minimum NTFS Permissions for ASP.Net on Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7

Hi I'm looking for something that will list the minimum NTFS permissions for ASP.NET 3.5 on a Windows 2008 Server. Particularly in regards the system folders and the account for the anonymous web user.

I'm used to working with .NET 1.1 on a Server 2003 Environment and can lock that down pretty well.

I'm working with a newly developed .net 3.5 application on Server 2008 and the anonymous web user account seems to want access to all sorts of areas of the server that would seem problematic (the root of C:\, the system32 folder, winsxs folders, etc) from a security perspective. I'm used to the older security model where you provided access to the Application Pool to a a few system areas and Anonymous Web User account got the Assembly and the .Net Framework and not much else. Anyone have a good reference for minimum recommended NTFS permissions for 3.5 App Pool and Web User Accts?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good start: [Administering ASP.NET Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy1xzbw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)